# Checkout field data validation min-words

Tags: checkout, validation, magento2.4.4

I've set this property (min-words) on some fields at the checkout page.

```
data-validate="{required:true, ' . "'min-words':2" . '}"'
```

It normally works perfectly with error text and preventing the customer checking out before 2 words have been filled. But when letters like ÆØÅ is used, it bypass the check and you can go on only writing 1 word in the fields??

Comment: Did you tried  data-validate="{'required':true, 'min-words':2}" ?

Comment: Yes, just as I wrote...